# verilog module expand tool

Tags: module, verilog, expand

Is there a tool that expands verilog modules as much as it can?
For example:

```
module and_gate(...);
    /* module description ... */
endmodule

module test(...);
    and_gate and1(...);
endmodule
```

In that example I would like the and_gate instance and1 in the test module to expand to the module description with the necessary modifications so that the module would compile (maybe prefix every element with the name of the instance, etc.).

Comment: Sounds like you want to flatten your hierarchy. Synthesis tool can generate a gate level flat netlist. I don't know of any out of the box software that can keep it as RTL. You could make your own script using something like [Verilog-Perl](http://www.veripool.org/wiki/verilog-perl) as a parser. Modules hierarchy allows partitioning and reuse so flattening does no have benefits until synthesis. Or maybe you are looking for a hierarchy browser, in which case an IDE (such as a verilog plug-in for Eclipse) will suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any tool that can do that, because:

- The synthesis process already does that: when a module is "called" from within another, that module is actually instantiated. That is, its contents (and the contents of any module that this module "calls" to) are included in the upper module
- For simulation, you want meagninful names for your nets and modules so your wave traces are easy to read and your possible mistakes easy to spot. Any tool that mangles net names so nets in simulations don't match nets in your design will give you a lot of headaches
- Anyway, I recall that Verilog functions and tasks behave mostly the way you ask. So do modules, but you won't get an updated source code with the expansion performed.